# $scope not updating when I go between pages

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, scope

I am working on an application that goes from template A to template B back to template A. On template A the user click on a button to get to template B. On template B the user add in an amount then hits submit. The program then goes back to template A and displays what was inputted in template B, but the number submitted is not updated in the scope and appears as null. For some reason when I start the application from Template B to Template A the scope is updated.

I am using a factory

```
 .factory('myService', function(){
  var budget = {
    limit: null
  };
  function set(data){
    budget.limit = data;
  }
  function get(){
    return budget.limit;
  }
  return{
    set: set,
    get: get,
    print: console.log(budget.limit)
  }
})
```

Here is my code for Template A called BudgetCalc

```
<ion-view view-title="BudgetCalc">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <a href="#/tab/dash/addBudget"><button>Start Budgeting</button></a>
    <h2>Your Limit is {{limit}}</h2>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And Template B named addBuget

```
<ion-view view-title="Add a Budget">
    <ion-content>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <span class="input-label">Set Spending Limit</span>
          <input type="number"ng-model="limit"> 
        </label>
        <button ui-sref="tab.budget" ng-click="setLimit(limit)">Submit</button>
        <br><h2>Your Limit is: {{limit}}</h2>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is are my Controllers for the two templates

```
.controller('BudgetCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.limit = myService.get();
  console.log("This is your limit " + $scope.limit);
})

.controller('SetLimitCtrl', function($scope, myService){
  $scope.setLimit = function(limit){
    if (limit != null) {
      myService.set(limit);
      console.log(myService.print);
    }  
  }
})
```

Comment: Every time you go back to view A, is the console.log in BudgetCtrl running?

Comment: No, It only runs the first time. When going back it does not display again.

Comment: When navigating back to view A add the reload option. $state.go('viewA'), {}, {reload: true})

Comment: May be I am totally wrong, but doesn't OP should be using a service module and not factory module if he wants to access data in two controller. Services are singleton whereas factories are instantiated everytime...

Answer (score 0):

You can share data between controllers using localstorage

```
.controller('SetLimitCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage){
  $scope.setLimit = function(limit){
    if (limit != null) {
      $localstorage.set("limit",limit);
      console.log($localstorage.get("limit"));
    }  
  }
})

.controller('BudgetCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage) {
  $scope.limit = $localstorage.get("limit");
  console.log("This is your limit " + $scope.limit);
  //// Dont forgot to clear limit when you complete the further process
})
```

Factory Localsoarage:

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function ($window) {
                return {
                    set: function (key, value) {
                        $window.localStorage[key] = value;
                    },
                    get: function (key, defaultValue) {
                        return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
                    },
                    setObject: function (key, value) {
                        $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
                    },
                    getObject: function (key, nulled) {
                        nulled = '[]';
                        try {
                            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '[]');
                        } catch (e) {
                        }
                    },
                    delete: function (key) {
                        $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
                    },
                };
            }])
```